# Getting text with accented characters using Python and Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, screen-scraping, latin

I made a scraping script with python and selenium. It scrapes data from a Spanish language website:

```
for i, line in enumerate(browser.find_elements_by_xpath(xpath)):
    tds = line.find_elements_by_tag_name('td')  # takes <td> tags from line
    print tds[0].text  # FIRST PRINT
    if len(tds)%2 == 0:  # takes data from lines with even quantity of cells only
        data.append([u"".join(tds[0].text), u"".join(tds[1].text), ])
    print data  # SECOND PRINT
```

The first print statement gives me a normal Spanish string. But the second print gives me a string like this: `"Data de Distribui\u00e7\u00e3o"`.
What's the reason for this?

Comment: could you show the original string, and the data in tds please?

Answer (score 3):

You are mixing encodings:

```
u'' # unicode string
b'' # bytearray string
```

The `text` property of `tds[0]` is a bytearray string which is encoding agnostic, and you are operating in the second print with unicode string, thus mixing the encodings

Answer (score 0):

for using any type of accented character we have to first encode or decode it before using them

```
accent_char = "ôâ"
name = accent_char.decode('utf-8')
print(name)
```

The above code will work for decoding the characters